# Verify this construction of a trapezoid given the length of each side

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Construct a trapezoid given the length of each side.

My solution is below.  I request verification, critique, improvements, or alternative approaches.

---

**Solution:** Let the parallel sides have lengths $b_1, b_2$ and the non-parallel sides $s_1, s_2$. Let $d = |b_1 - b_2|$.

Construct $\triangle ADX$ so that $AD = s_1, AX = s_2, DX = d$.  Extend $DX$ to $C$ so that $DC = b_1$.  Draw $AB$ with length $b_2$ parallel to $DC$.  To show that $ABCD$ is the desired trapezoid, it is sufficient to show that $AX \cong BC$.

[image]

Observe that $ABCX$ is a parallelogram since $AB \cong XC$ and $AB \parallel XC$.  Therefore $AX \cong BC$, completing the proof.

Comment: Could you please draw and label a figure?

Comment: How do you show that this is the only possible trapezoid with those sides, asides from exchanging the nonparallel sides?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Diagram added.

Comment: @martycohen You can start with the final trapezoid $ABCD$ and work each step in reverse.  Choose $X$ on the longer base, on the side closest to $s_1$.  Then each step is fully determined.